# Do sums of infinite series have "critical points" where removing some set of values causes them to converge?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For instance, the harmonic series

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n} $$

does not converge, but the rieman zeta function $ \zeta(s) $

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^s} $$

gives $ \zeta(2) \approx 1.644934 $. Another way to look at $\zeta(2)$ is something like "Start with the harmonic series; take the first term, then skip 2 terms. Add the next term, then skip 4 terms. Add the next term, then skip 6 terms, and so on increasing the number skipped by 2 each iteration."

Somewhere "in between" the harmonic series and the $\zeta(2)$ series this sum converges to a finite value (right?). Example of what I mean by "in between":

"Start with the harmonic series; take the sum of every other term"

or

"Start with the harmonic series; take 1, skip 2, take 1, skip 3, take 1, skip 4, take 1, skip 5, etc"

How can I find some "minimal" definition for when the series converges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $s > 1$, $s$ a real number. Choose an integer $N > 1$,
and let $M$ be the integer such that
$$
\frac{1}{N+M - 1} > \frac{1}{N^s} \geq \frac{1}{N+M} .
$$
That is, $M = \lceil N^s \rceil - N$.

Let $(a_n)$ be the sequence such that
$a_n = \frac1n$ when $1 \leq n < N + M$,
and $a_n = \lceil (n - M)^s \rceil^{-1}$ when $n \geq N + M$.
Then I think you'll find that $\sum a_n$ converges.
But by making $N$ larger you can delay the first "dropped" term as
late in the sequence as you like,
and by making $s$ smaller (as long as $s > 1$) you can make
the "rate" at which you drop terms as "slow" as you want.

I don't think there is any "minimal" set of terms to remove
in the sense you're looking for.

Comment: Accepting this, because *I think* it helped me answer my own question, which I phrased a bit differently at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1974323/114910

Answer (score 0):

Adding or removing a finite number of terms from an infinite sum makes no difference to its convergence. So it doesn't make sense to ask for a "critical" or "minimal" set of indices whose presence is required for the sum to diverge.

Comment: None of the examples I gave removed a finite number of terms.

Comment: Your proposed "critical" sequence would need to be invariant under the addition or removal of a finite number of terms.