# What is the minimum value the Riemann zeta floor function converges?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let the Riemann zeta floor (RZF) function be

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\lfloor n^s \rfloor} $$

For $s=1$ this is the harmonic series, and for $s=2$ this is $\zeta(2)$.

The harmonic series does not converge, but $\zeta(2)$ does (As RZF does for all $s>1$). At what minimum $s$ does RZF converge?

I think I have an informal answer, I'm just trying to make sure this is a reasonable approach.

informal outline of my answer follows:

Consider the harmonic series with every (finite) $m4 terms removed. For example, every other term removed:

$$ \frac 1 2 + \frac 1 4 + \frac 1 6 + \cdots $$

This can be written as

$$ \frac 1 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 n $$

and so this series does not converge because the harmonic series does not converge. Thus (hand-waving) multiplying $\operatorname{RZF}(s=1)$ by a constant factor isn't sufficient for convergence.

For $s>1$, this has the effect of removing an increasing number of terms from the harmonic series as n gets larger (I believe this increasing number of terms removed is what's key...). The ratio test gives

$$ \frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac { \lfloor n^s \rfloor }{ \lfloor (n+1)^s \rfloor } $$

which tends towards zero for sufficiently large $n$ and $s>1$, implying the series converges. Therefore, the "minimum" requirements for RZF to converge is any $s>1$.

Comment: it is obvious it converges for $s > 1$, with the same argument as for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}$

Comment: If it was obvious to me I wouldn't have asked.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{n^s} \le \frac{1}{\lfloor n^s \rfloor} < \frac{2}{n^s}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $n^s - 1 < \lfloor n^s \rfloor \leq n^s$.  Then standard comparison test tricks wll get you your result.  For instance, eventually, $n^s - 1 > n^s / 2$.